# Sorting data in datagridview by gender

Tags: vb.net, sorting, datagridview, combobox

I want to sort data in datagridview by gender using a combobox. In my combobox there are two options (male and female). If the user select female in the combobox i want the datagridview to display all female students only and if the user select male i want the datagridview to display all male students only.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Change the sql to include the gender using an `Order By` clause.

Comment: Ive never tried anything coz i really dont know how to do it mystia. Do u have any idea?

Comment: That is filtering not sorting. Now ask the Google "filter by combobox" and see what he says.

Answer (score 0):

Below it's a sample of what you are looking for. You have to add manually the options Male and Female.

Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
        Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM "TableName" WHERE SEX='" & ComboBox1.SelectedItem & "'"
        Dim dataadapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(sql, connection)
        Dim ds As New DataSet()
        dataadapter.Fill(ds, "ContactsbySex")

```
    DataGridView1.DataSource = ds
    DataGridView1.DataMember = "ContactsbySex"
End Sub
```